# Java 8 : Multiple conditions in map function of stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How to use multiple condtions in map function of stream ? I'm new to Java streams actually I want to use multiple condtions in a stream map something like:

```
List<String> cs = Arrays.asList("agent", "manager", "admin");

List<String> replace = cs.stream()
.map(p -> p.equals("agent") ? "manager" : p || p.equals("manager") ? "agent" : p )
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

What I want is to replace agent with manager and manager with agent. That's if in a list agent exist replace it with manager and if manager exist replace it with agent.

Comment: And your question is? Also: Strings are not compared using ``==`` but using ``.equals``.

Comment: why is used the `map` instead the `filter`?

Comment: @HadiJ because ``map`` is exactly what you want here, how is ``filter`` going to help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may do it like so,

```
List<String> interchanged = cs.stream()
    .map(s -> s.equals("manager") ? "agent" : s.equals("agent") ? "manager" : s)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do that using `List.replaceAll` could be:

```
List<String> cs = Arrays.asList("agent", "manager", "admin");
cs.replaceAll(s -> {
    if (s.equals("manager")) {
        return "agent";
    }
    if (s.equals("agent")) {
        return "manager";
    }
    return s;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers show how to deal with 2 options to replace elements. Here's a more general approach:

```
Map<String, String> replacements = Map.of("agent", "manager", "manager", "agent");

List<String> replace = cs.stream()
    .map(p -> replacements.getOrDefault(p, p))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you have more words to be replaced, simply add them to the `replacements` map.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> replace = cs.stream()
                .map(p -> p.equals("agent") ? "manager" : p.equals("manager") ? "agent" : p )
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will help you in this case but if you need more conditions use body style smth like this

```
map(p -> {...})
```

for creating readable code.

Comment: Same as [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53081456/1746118)

Answer (score 0):

*For readability you can check this*

```
List<String> cs = Arrays.asList("agent", "manager", "admin");

List<String> replace = cs.stream()
.map(p -> { 
  if(p.equals("agent"))
   p = "manager"; 
  else if(p.equals("manager"))
   p = "agent; 

  return p;
})
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Maybe opinion based, but for some reasons I find the code in Ravindra's answer more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be like this:

```
cs.replaceAll(s->s.replaceAll("agent|manager",replace(s)));



String replace(String s){
    return s.equals("manager")?"agent" :s.equals("agent")?"manager": s;
}
```